# can i get html tabel column sum by using only css?

Tags: css

can I get column sum in CSS only? im using weasyprint which does not support js/Jq so I have to calculate the sum anyhow and i don't know how will I do it.

```
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        counter-reset: sum;
    }
td[data-value] { counter-increment: sum attr(data-value) } 
thead tr::after { content: counter(sum) }
```

but it always show zero

Comment: I don’t think this is possible currently as attr support on other than the content property is ‘sparse’ according to MDN but in any case converting to integer is not supported on any browser currently. Also,, are you saying that the content of a cell will also be held in an attribute in your table?

Comment: i guess your r8. `attr` is not supported other than `content`.



im not sure what you mean by your question

Comment: Your code implies that what you want to sum together are some attributes of the cells - e.g. <td data-value="123">The content of the cell</td> but normally I would have expected the user to want to sum together what they can see, the number held in the cell e.g. <td>123</td>

Comment: Ah i get it now.   It was just an example to somehow get the values.... From a cell of table.... I just wanted to show the sum of a column using its cell value...

Comment: CSS doesn't know anything about contents of elements. You can't get the sum of the contents of the cells using CSS - you need Javascript.